# Parsing same element name in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am not getting that how to differentiate same element name for eg City,Area in two different trees. So help me for this in parsing the same element name in iphone.

```
<Contacts id="1">
    <Fname>Siddharth</Lname>
    <Lname>Chopra</Lname>
    <Currentaddress>
        <Area>Aundh</Area>
        <City>Pune</City>
        <Phone>8796xxxx</Phone>
    </Currentaddress>
    <Permanentaddress>
        <Area>Bhatar</Area>
        <City>Surat</City>
        <Phone>989825xxxx</Phone>
    </Permanentaddress>
    </Contacts>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have implemented the delegate methods didstartElement,didFoundCharacter & didElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class create an mutable array, that you'll use as a stack.
if a new element starts, create a object representing it (a custom (managed) object, or a dictionary) and add it to the array. In `didFoundCharacter:` alter the object, that is last on the array. If `didEndElement:` is called, save it either to core data, a file, sql or in memory to another array. and remove it from the array.

If the elements `<Area>`,`<City>` or `<Phone>`are handled, you'll know, that the object on the second last position is the address, they belong to. either `<Currentaddress>` or `<Permanetaddress>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a flag in `didstartElement`, the value of the flag will let you know, which parent tree is under parsing process.